# Date Time Picker - Setting Opening Date and Time

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using this nifty little date and time picker [ http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ ].  How can I set the date and time for when the picker opens?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using this on a form, set it from a hidden input.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Date").datetimepicker({
            ampm: true
        });

        var date = new Date(
            Date.parse(
                $('#DatePicker').val(),
                "mm/dd/yyyy hh:MM tt"
            )
        );
        $('#Date').datetimepicker('setDate', date);
    });
```

HTML Form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="DatePicker" />
<input type="text" id="DatePicker" value="fromyourdatabase" />
```

Comment: I spent hours on this and finally your solution found... it worked perfect... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

> Try this
>
> ```
> $('#dtpkr').datetimepicker();
> ```
>
> Then add
>
> ```
> $('#dtpkr').datetimepicker('setDate', (new Date()));
> ```
>
> This will give you the current date and time

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a `Date` object to the `setDate` method.

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker().click(function() {
    $(this).datetimepicker('setDate',new Date(2011, 11, 20, 8, 30));
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/Rkewu/1/.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `value` attribute inside the `input` element like this:

```
<input id="example1" value="05/05/2011" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just focus it.

```
$('#totTb').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    timeSuffix: " Z"       
}).focus(function () { $('#totTb').datetimepicker('setDate', d) });
```